# Как изменить манифест Docker'а?

Tags: windows, asp.net, docker

Написал некий сайт на ASP.Net Core 3.1, положил его в Docker. Потом решил перейти на пятую версию ASP.Net Core. Перешёл. В IIS всё работает нормально. А при попытке упаковать в Docker получаю ошибку:

*CTC1014    Docker command failed with exit code 1.
manifest for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:5.0 not found: manifest unknown: manifest tagged by "5.0" is not found*

Непосредственно в Dockerfile изменения внёс.
Где и что ещё нужно исправить, чтобы проект опять упаковывался в Docker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После того как они убрали `Core` из названия, Microsoft обновила и названия образов, сейчас должно быть так `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0`

Comment: Спасибо, дружище! Работает!